# react ant design date time picker select date option issue

Tags: reactjs, date, antd, react-typescript

Im using **[ant design 3 date time picker](https://gary-shen.github.io/ant-design/components/date-picker/)** for my react project, and im  disabled the when the user  select the `date/time` of `present/future`, and `disable all the past dates`, its working good, but i have some conflict on that my function.

**here the conflict**

when i select future date and time after display again select date button on the footer so im select again 
today date, display the future time with today date , any solution for disable `select date` button link

you can understand my conflict, please use  the **[stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wmc25i)**

**here my code**

```
interface AppProps { }
interface AppState {
  name: string; 
  date: Date;
}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      date: new Date()
    };
  }
//date disable
    disabledDate(current: any) {
        // Can not select days before today and today
        //return current && current < moment().endOf('day');
        return current && current < moment().startOf("day")
    }

    //time disable
    getDisabledHours() {
        var hours = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < moment().hour(); i++) {
            hours.push(i);
        }
        return hours;
    }

    //time disable
    getDisabledMinutes = (selectedHour: any) => {
        var minutes = [];
        if (selectedHour === moment().hour()) {
            for (var i = 0; i < moment().minute(); i++) {
                minutes.push(i);
            }
        }
        return minutes;
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
   name="Date" disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
   onChange={d => this.setState({date: d})}
   style={{width: "100%"}}
   showTime={{ disabledMinutes: moment().date() < moment(this.state.date).date() ? undefined : this.getDisabledMinutes, 
   disabledHours: moment().date() < moment(this.state.date).date() ? undefined : this.getDisabledHours}}
   value={moment(this.state.date)}

  />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: question is not clear to me

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress Hello there,  1st select future  date and  `select time`  8 am or 7 am, , then again click  `select date`  and pick  today date , when i click the   1st time  future date  and 7 or 8am . that time display with today date, because i m disabled past time with today date , that is a issue , you can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wmc25i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i can do is create a new function to handle the date change

```
setSelectedDate = (date: any) => {
  const now = moment();  //get current date time
  const isFuture = date.isAfter(now); //check selected date is a future date compared to current date and time
  this.setState({date: isFuture ? date: now.toDate()}); //if it's a future date then assign the slected date else select the current date and time
}
```

and change the onChange props as

```
<DatePicker
   name="Date" disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
   onChange={d => this.setSelectedDate(d)}
.....
```

Here is the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-frrfm9?file=index.tsx)

Comment: Hello, can i asked some question  for you?  how can i added place holder for this? when i added placeholder that moment not working

Comment: can you please send me stackblitz of it, so i can check it for you

Comment: Hello, here the link  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jddtiq?file=index.tsx

Comment: @core114 what is the issue there step by step pls?

Comment: I added  `placeholder="Select Date & Time"` for the my code, see the above link, then your solution not working , that part  not working   `value={moment(this.state.date)}`, i removed the placeholder  that time solution working, but i need to add placeholder, any solution for this? i set your code to my code  with `setDate` function

Comment: @core114 check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-sm6yys?file=index.tsx

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and solution